# How to find difference between list and dict in python

Tags: python

I have one array which can return a list or dict, how to find the difference?

Ex:

```
val = { 'sum':'10', 'sub':'5', 'mul':'25', 'div':'1' }
```

(or)

```
val = [ { 'sum':'10', 'sub':'5',  'mul':'25',  'div':'1' },
        { 'sum':'20', 'sub':'10', 'mul':'100', 'div':'1' }]
```

Comment: You don't have an 'array'. You have a `dict` or a `list`. Why do you want to know what `val` is?

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Type checking is rarely necessary in Python. How come this `val` can contain different types, and why does it matter?

Comment: Arrays never `return` anything. What is that thing you call `array`?

Comment: I am formatting some data, and returning dict. Some of the data should be formatted in the form of list of dict's.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you only need to check for dict and list, you can use `isinstance`

```
>>> val = { 'sum':'10', 'sub':'5', 'mul':'25', 'div':'1' }
>>> isinstance(val, list)
False
>>> isinstance(val, dict)
True
>>>
```

Comment: Yes, that can be done. But why? In Python we don't look before we leap.

Comment: @Tichodroma: Yes, I know. But OP specifically wanted to know how they could differentiate list and dict.

Answer (score 4):

If your question is about type checking then you can use `isinstance`:

```
>>> val = { 'sum':'10', 'sub':'5', 'mul':'25', 'div':'1' }
>>> isinstance(val, dict)
True

>>> val = [ { 'sum':'10', 'sub':'5', 'mul':'25', 'div':'1' }, { 'sum':'20', 'sub':'10', 'mul':'100', 'div':'1' }]
>>> isinstance(val, list)
True
```

help on `isinstance`:

```
>>> print isinstance.__doc__
isinstance(object, class-or-type-or-tuple) -> bool

Return whether an object is an instance of a class or of a subclass thereof.
With a type as second argument, return whether that is the object's type.
The form using a tuple, isinstance(x, (A, B, ...)), is a shortcut for
isinstance(x, A) or isinstance(x, B) or ... (etc.).
```

Answer (score 0):

`isinstance(val, dict)` vs `isinstance(val, list)`